# Powershell aliases location

Tags: powershell, alias

If I run PowerShell at work and run command `alias`, this is what I get:
[image]

Where are those Aliases stored and how can I add (my own) permanent one to that list?

Comment: Good question, should be upvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From **[`Get-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-5.1)** documentation:

> The Get-Alias cmdlet gets the aliases in the current session. This
>   includes **built-in** aliases, aliases that you have **set or imported**, and
>   aliases that you have added to your **Windows PowerShell profile**.

You can user **[`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-5.1)** to set your own. E.g. from documentation:

```
PS C:\> Set-Alias -Name list -Value get-childitem
```

---

- **built-in** - There is no need to modify these.
- **set or imported** - You can use `Set-Alias` as described above. This will be lost when you close the session. You can also `Export-Alias` at the end of a session, and `Import-Alias` at the start of a new one.
- **[Windows PowerShell Profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx)** - I recommend using this method as it will automatically run every time you start a new session. The documentation goes into detail about different profiles and their scopes (shell or ISE or both? all users or just you?)

  The simplest way to user PowerShell Profile:

  - Go to `C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`
    If the WindowsPowerShell folder does not exist, create it.
  - Create new file `Profile.ps1` that contains your code.  Example below.

---

```
Set-Alias -Name eg -Value www

Function www {
    cd "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects"
}
```

Comment: [From the MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-5.1) "Unless you add the alias to the Windows PowerShell profile, the changes to an alias are lost when you exit the session or close Windows PowerShell."

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx) is the doc on PowerShell profiles.

Comment: Add the command to your profile. There are multiple different profiles depending on how and who is launching powershell. There are plenty of descriptions on the web.

Comment: @lewis4u Shell aliases on Linux behave exactly the same way. Unless you define them e.g. in your `.bashrc` they're lost when you exit from the current shell.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes exactly, that is the reason I thought there is a file for those aliases and I just wanted to add my own, but in PS the things are different, alias does not accept second parameter so you need to make a function.

Comment: @lewis4u Umm, no, it's not different. Not the way you define a persistent alias, that is. Write your alias definition to one of the [PowerShell profiles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx) to make it persistent. The main difference between PowerShell and bash aliases is that in PowerShell you can alias only command/function *names*, not entire statements.

Comment: Yes, just like you said: "The main difference between PowerShell and bash aliases is that in PowerShell you can alias only command/function names, not entire statements." that was the problem for me because I didn't know that!